# When use create() the fillable values come null

Tags: laravel

i have an array with values that i am trying to insert it in the database, but when i use `create()` the values are inserted as null in database while if i use `insert()` the values insert correct.

This is the code from the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'order_number' => 'required',
        'client' => 'required',
        'products' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);
   for($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++)
   {
       $values[] = [
         'order_number' => $request->order_number,
         'client' => $request->client,
         'products' => $request->products[$i],
         'amount' => $request->amount[$i],
         'description' => $request->description
       ];
   }
    Order::create($values);
    return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Order Saved successfully!');
}
```

and this is the code from the model

```
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'order_number',
    'client',
    'products',
    'amount',
    'description',
];
```

The names are the same and in the database, any reason why the values come null when i use `create()` method?

Comment: I think you should add a foreach for the create `foreach ($values as $value) { Order::create($value); }`

Comment: @geertjanknapen okay i will try the foreach

Comment: What's the point of for() loop in this case @geertjanknapen ?

Comment: try Order::insert($values);

Comment: You are doing correct thing by forming whole array of data to be inserted, then inserting it in one attempt. Try `createMany` method. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

Comment: @JohnLobo with insert the values are inserted but timestamp is null

Comment: @Tpojka do i add `createMany` on my model?

Comment: I left you link to docs. `createMany` is inbuilt method, you don't need to create it.

Comment: @StewieSWS Better late than never, it seems he's creating an array `values` with multiple arrays in it (since he uses a for loop for every product) so that would mean that 1 entry in the `values` array is an array with correct data for the model, meaning that by looping over the array he can insert `Order` for that data.

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes thats what im doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert()` method accepts multiple objects in form of arrays to be created, for example :

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
  ['email' => 'picard@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
  ['email' => 'janeway@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
]);
```

But `create()` method does not accept such structure. You cannot create multiple entries using this method. So in this case you either keep using `insert()`, either move your `create()` inside for loop.

**Edit** : `createMany()` works only on relationships, and apparently DB manipulation in loops is antipattern. In that case you can do something like this :

```
$created_at = now();
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++)
{
   $values[] = [
     'order_number' => $request->order_number,
     'client' => $request->client,
     'products' => $request->products[$i],
     'amount' => $request->amount[$i],
     'description' => $request->description,
     'created_at' => $created_at,
     'updated_at' => $created_at,
   ];
}

Order::insert($values);
```

Comment: even when i put the `create()` inside the for loop the values come null, but when i use insert the timestamps come null i need all the values together.

Comment: If you put create() inside for loop, what do you pass to it as parameter?

Comment: i put this `Order::create($values);` inside the for loop

Comment: Well, that's incorrect. With each for iteration you are appending $values. Instead, you can write directly into create(). I'll edit my answer to show

Comment: so how should i do it?

Comment: DB manipulation in loop is anti-pattern. Never use it in production.

Comment: @StewieSWS so how should be used then?

Comment: try with createMany(), using your old structure

Comment: @StewieSWS i get an error `Call to undefined method App\Models\Order::createMany()`

Comment: @laraCoder tried it, apparently method `createMany()` works only on relationships. It means that apart from `insert()` there are no other options to create multiple records in Laravel, which is upsetting. You can try to add timestamps manually in your  for loop and then use `insert()` method

Comment: @StewieSWS do you have any documentation how to make it work with `createMany()`

Comment: @laraCoder edited my answer again :) I think it should work with insert()